Invariants arising from 3D Yang-Mills
3D Chern-Simons theory is well-known for producing knot invariants and other interesting 3-manifold invariants.

Does a similar story exist for 3D Yang-Mills, i.e. a solid understanding of the Riemannian manifold invariants that arise? 2D and 4D seem to be well-studied, but I am not finding so much for 3D.

Is my understanding correct that due to Mostow rigidity, an invariant of a hyperbolic 3-manifold arising in question #1 would necessarily be topological?

Is there a relationship between 3D Yang-Mills and 3D Chern-Simons invariants?


Thanks in advance!

3d Yang-Mills theory isn't a topological QFT.  It depends non-trivially on the 3-manifold's Riemannian metric, and thus, for example, its expectation values transform non-trivially when we rescale the metric.
You can sometimes recover a topological field theory by finding observables whose expectation values remain non-trivial in the low-energy / long wavelength limit, when you make the manifold so large that there are no propagating degrees of freedom.  To be pedantic, this is always possible, but in a lot of cases the only thing that survives in this limit is a unique lowest energy state, acted on by a scalar, a trivial limit.  But sometimes you have multiple lowest energy states with interesting dynamics and interesting observables.
In 3d Yang-Mills theory, it's generally believed that the long wavelength limit exists and is non-trivial, and moreover is Chern-Simons theory.  So it's not expected that we find any new topological invariants of Riemannian manifolds this way.
